# State Variable of solidity Contract could not be updated through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have following contract and just want to update its state variable values i.e. totalSupply. But when I try to attempt this task through JavaScript code (given below) by calling its function i.e. setTotalSupply, tts values is not updated.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract MyContract {

    uint256 totalSupply; 
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    address owner;

    constructor(address payable _wallet) public {
        totalSupply = 10;
        owner = _wallet;
    }

    function () external payable{
        buyToken();
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        require(totalSupply >= (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2);
        balances[msg.sender] += (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;
        // wallet.tranfer(msg.value);
        totalSupply -=(msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;

    }
    function getTotalSupply()public view returns  (uint256 ){
        return totalSupply;
    }
       function setTotalSupply(uint256 newSupply)public {
        require(msg.sender == owner && totalSupply<1);
        totalSupply = newSupply;

    }
    function getBalance() public view returns  (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

i just want to update its value i.e. total supply.
following is my JavaScript code for above purpose

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/7fb0bdc97c.....");
 const web3 = new Web3(provider);

var contract1  = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress1)
const txData2 = contract1.methods.setTotalSupply(10).encodeABI(); 
setSupplyBalance(contractAddress1, txData2);

function setSupplyBalance(contractAddress, txData ){

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
      txObject = {
      nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('100', 'gwei')),
      to: contractAddress,
      value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
      data:txData
    }




  const tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
// sign the trx
tx.sign(privateKey1)

serializedTx = tx.serialize()

raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction (raw, (err, txHash)=> {
    console.log('err:', err)
    console.log('txHash', txHash)
  })

  })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

I think I found the reason. You didn't give the `_wallet` variable in constructor correct address while deploying the contract, so it won't pass the require statement in setTotalSupply.

---

Is totalSupply equal to 0 when you call setTotalSupply?

Because you have a require statement in setTotalSupply, if it is not 0, the transaction will be reverted and the value of totalSupply will not be updated.

Comment: yes , when I consumed all my tokens (totalSupply) and confirmed it. After confirmation, i call setTotalSupply with value 10. My trx executed successfully and become a part of contract and block as well. But totalSupply value remained zero..

Comment: May I have your contract address?

Comment: actually, i am doing on someone else project , which is not actually ethereum, but it uses ethereum as their source code (with some little  changes...)

Comment: I guess it went to the fallback function, could you try to send the transaction with 1 wei and see does it fail?

Comment: I just deployed that contract (0x66CfBc4C8fC163faf502715963C12216188D4Be1) on ethereum and calling setTotalSupply (through making trx with value =0, value=100gwei or without value parameter .. all are in vein... could you help me .. ? and received this error txHash 0x730c7466c7681b7f214316c9e93f8bcfdc631260b13afddc91202d6c3854e66d
(node:200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverte
d by the EVM:

Comment: msg.sender != owner

Comment: No i have deployed and setTotalSupply with same account... also i have tried to skip above whole condition (i.e. require(msg.sender == owner && totalSupply<1, but still could not successful ..

Comment: Actually, I just checked the explorer, and it seems like you didn't pass it the argument at all for deployment. How do you deploy the contract? Through remix or something else?

Comment: I checked its working on Remix as well. However, I have deployed through web3 .. .

Comment: Could you provide the code for deployment?
I just traced the failed transaction, and that's the reason why it was reverted.

Comment: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account3, (err, txCount) => {
      txObject = {
      nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
      data:abiData
    }
tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
tx.sign(privateKey3)
serializedTx = tx.serialize()

raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')
// console.log(raw);
//broadcast tx
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction (raw, (err, txHash)=> {
    console.log('err:', err)
    console.log('txHash', txHash)
})

  })
}

Comment: You should append your address to the abiData.

For example: 00000000000000000000000072186a1d8c9818a508729a29d56a8fd0899273da
, Where 0x72186a1d8c9818a508729a29d56a8fd0899273da is my address, remember to add zero so that it has length of 64.

Comment: this is my new contract as per your guidance.. 0xA8FdDF33D4DBb2622c992e8AF3d720941b5b8F04.... but all in vein.. same error..(node:192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverte
d by the EVM:

Comment: @AmirAli totalSupply is not 0 now. So if you did not remove the require statement then it will revert.

Comment: I have removed require statement , already in my contract. then why it still reverting...

Comment: Is setTotalSupply function payable? Because you sent the transaction with value.
Try set value to 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201998/discussion-between-amir-ali-and-stillfantasy).

Comment: calling with value 0 is worked for me ... thanks @StillFantasy

Comment: Hi @AmirAli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

making payable totalSupply and function setTotalSupply , then made trx with value zero will solved this error...